# How do I manage increasing clip version in Unity meta data when using git?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, meta

We have Unity under version control using Git and Gitea.
Everytime we open our current branch, many meta files are "changed" as the following:
[image: userData: ClipVersion increases]

Within some art asset .meta files:
`userData: ClipVersion=10` becomes   `userData: ClipVersion=11`
On different files the numbers differ, but always increment by 1.

Any advice on properly getting git to play along, or any suggestions on handling asset store packages in git is appreciated.

This is our .gitignore:

```
# ---> Unity
# This .gitignore file should be placed at the root of your Unity project directory
#
# Get latest from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore
#
/[Ll]ibrary/
/[Tt]emp/
/[Oo]bj/
/[Bb]uild/
/[Bb]uilds/
/[Ll]ogs/
/[Uu]ser[Ss]ettings/

# MemoryCaptures can get excessive in size.
# They also could contain extremely sensitive data
/[Mm]emoryCaptures/

# Asset meta data should only be ignored when the corresponding asset is also ignored
!/[Aa]ssets/**/*.meta

# Uncomment this line if you wish to ignore the asset store tools plugin
# /[Aa]ssets/AssetStoreTools*

# Autogenerated Jetbrains Rider plugin
/[Aa]ssets/Plugins/Editor/JetBrains*

# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/

# Gradle cache directory
.gradle/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
*.mdb
*.opendb
*.VC.db

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.pdb.meta
*.mdb.meta

# Unity3D generated file on crash reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.aab
*.unitypackage

# Crashlytics generated file
crashlytics-build.properties

# Packed Addressables
/[Aa]ssets/[Aa]ddressable[Aa]ssets[Dd]ata/*/*.bin*

# Temporary auto-generated Android Assets
/[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa.meta
/[Aa]ssets/[Ss]treamingAssets/aa/*

# *KinematicaBinary*
```

[EDIT 1]
When the other dev pulls the files, Unity again imprts and allas, the meta files have changed!
We also utilize git branching.

Comment: Does it affect your models/animations? Otherwise why not simply commit it along? ;)

Comment: Yes, why not `git commit` your changes as you make code along, or why not create branches for major sets of changes(say a particular feature you are going to develop) and then work on those branches

Comment: Thank you both for your help! I have edited the post with extra info.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "AssetImporter.userData" in your project including the code in your Assets folder and the code in your Packages.
This is the API for changing the userData in .meta files.
Or you can search for "ClipVersion=".

I guess you have kinematica in your project packages. I ran into the same problem.